# Docker Save Logs To Host's Directory

Tags: docker, .net-core

I am writing to a Text File within my Docker Container, Path inside container is /app/data/text.txt

When I run my APP, it writes to this files just fine, however I want to write this to my HOST system, not within the container. so I tried below

```
docker run -v /home/pi/mmm:/app/data  -d smartazanmobilebackgroundservice
```

and still i cant see any text.txt file in my /home/pi/data folder

My Working dir for my Docker app is ...

```
WORKDIR /app
```

.Net Code to get directory is

```
string logPath = Path.Combine("data");
```

Comment: I'd expect that command to produce an error along the lines of `-v: no such command`: `docker run` options like `-v` need to appear _before_ the image name, anything after the image name is taken as the command to run.

Comment: see my edit, i tried it...no luck.

Comment: Can you add more details about how you write to the file please e.g. `StreamWriter`, `File.WriteLine` etc.? Also, does the directory `/app/data` already exist? Thanks

Comment: i got it to work, placement of -v was the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -v /home/pi/mmm:/app/data  -d smartazanmobilebackgroundservice
```

I was using -v after the Image Name.